# Trying to detect "touch up" from a UIImageView that has not been tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

An image is worth a thousand words :)

[image: Click a button,show an imageview and then close the imageview by lifting the finger]

The scenario is as follows: I want to press a UIButton and then show a UIImageView in full screen (that I have done!). Then I need to hide the Image View by detecting that the finger has been lifted from the screen.

What I have tried, unsuccessfully:

1. Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image view and enable `userInteractionEnabled`.

   ```
   let tap_to_close_ref = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap_to_close:")

   tap_to_close_ref.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

   self.addGestureRecognizer(tap_to_close_ref)
   ```

The problem is that the UIImageView does not recognise the tap unless it has been initiated by the image itself.

2. I subclassed UIImageView and listened to `touchesBegan` event, the same problem again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show UIImageView in button's `touchDownInside`, and hine in `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside`

Comment: this would only be valid when one lifts his finger **inside** the button, not if he slides the finger and lifts it up

Comment: Just an idea: How about a fullscreen transparent view above the UIImage and let this view handle the taps...?

Comment: @zisoft so when I click the button I should both open UIImageView and transparent UIView? Will UIView do something more that UIImageView cannot do? I don't think so.

Comment: I think the problem is related due to changing the view under the user's finger: User touches the button, the button is removed and the image appears. So you lose control about the touch event. Therefore my idea to use a fullscreen view which is always on top and handles the touch events.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `UIImageView` `userInteractionEnabled` property, which by default is set to `NO`.

EDIT:

Then the easy solution which comes to mind is leave the `UIImageView` interaction to `NO` and track the touch with the underlying button.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and made one small change.  Remove the ":" at the end of declaring the action.

change "tap_to_close:" to "tap_to_close"